# how to make angularjs e2e-test auto reload after code change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

when I run the e2e-testing, it does it job but then disconnects when the tests succeed. Is there a way to just have it continuously test?

```
./scripts/e2e-test.sh 

Starting Testacular Server (http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
info: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/
info (launcher): Starting browser Chrome
info (Chrome 24.0): Connected on socket id E1loZJU6dCI4eyW9ewyo
Chrome 24.0: Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (1.027 secs / 0.697 secs)
info: Disconnecting all browsers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your testacular/karma config, change/add

```
autoWatch = True 
singleRun = False
```

You can find the config by opening up your ./scripts/e2e-test.sh and where it says testacular start or karma start the file name should be there. I'm assuming you are using the angular seed or tutorial, in which case the file is located at the config folder usually under something.conf.js